# Trying to POST API command in Python Google Webrisk but cant figure out the authentication

Tags: python, authentication

here is the guide from Google: https://cloud.google.com/web-risk/docs/submission-api-v2#curl

To be honest it is not very clear, or im being especially slow . so i know typically for APIs, you pass a key and secret like `s.auth = (auth_key, auth_secret)` assuming you defined auth_key etc.

```
However, for the webrisk one, i cannot figure out what the API command would be, i got this far:

g_head = {"key": "KEYIGOTFROMGOOGLEHERE"}

google_post = s.post('https://webrisk.googleapis.com/v1/projects/phishing-project-NUMBER/uris:submit',headers=g_head, verify=False, json={
 "submission": {
    "uri": "http://BADDOMAIN.com",
  },
})

google_submit_response = google_post.json()

print(google_submit_response)
```

i keep getting errors of "

> request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth
> 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

"

I did download a json file from Google API account that contains the following if that useful (although i am not sure where and how to use it in the code):

```
"type": "service_account"
"project_id": "XXXXXXXX"
"private_key_id": "XXXXX"
"private_key": "-----BEG
"client_email": "XXXXXXX"
"client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX"
"auth_uri": "https://acc"
"token_uri": "https://oa"
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "XXX"
"client_x509_cert_url": "XXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can test exactly in the same conditions than that tutorial, I would start by this (to make sure it works with your credentials).
https://cloud.google.com/web-risk/docs/submission-api-v2#curl

Then, you may try by modifying the following line

```py
g_head = {"key": "KEYIGOTFROMGOOGLEHERE"}
```

with

```py
g_head = {"Authorization": "Bearer KEYIGOTFROMGOOGLEHERE"}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! tried that but unfortunately doesnt work. its just that their documentation is horrid for off g_console work and ive never worked with bearer tokens before

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, I've found this documentation about an library developed by google for webrisk : https://googleapis.dev/python/webrisk/latest/index.html